# SwiftUI: Extending the Image type to return an image processed through a method

Tags: image, swiftui, extension-methods

This approach does not work for me and I can't figure out how to do it.

````
extension Image {
    func getResizedImage(_ imageName: String) -> any View {
        return Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
    }
}

// then ...

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image.getResizedImage("myImageFromAssets")
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Because you're calling this on `Image`, you need a `static` function
2. The function should return `some View`, not `any View`

```
extension Image {
    static func getResizedImage(_ imageName: String) -> some View {
        return Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image.getResizedImage("myImageFromAssets")
    }
}
```